# Discord bot supposed to clear 3 messages but it will only clear 2 messages

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a clear command which deletes the messages you would like to. But when I say `!clear 10` it'll delete only 9 messages.

```
const bot = new Discord.Client();

const token = 'hello there! :)';

const PREFIX = '!';

bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('This bot is online!');
})

bot.on('message', message => {

    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

    switch (args[0]) {
case 'clear':
            if (!args[1]) return message.reply('Please specify the number of messages to clear `e.g. !clear 10`')
                .then(message => message.delete({ timeout: 5000 }));
            if (!message.member.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === "Owner") && !message.member.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === "Admin") && !message.member.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === "Moderator")) {
                return message.reply('You do not have permissions to clear!')
                    .then(message => message.delete({ timeout: 5000 }));
            }
            message.channel.bulkDelete(args[1]);
            break;
        }       
    })
    
bot.login(token);
```

Comment: Can you console log your args[1]?

Answer (score 0):

It actually deletes 10 messages but the command adds 1 message to the chat so u think it deleted 9 to delete the command also use message.delete() after the bulkdelete like so

```
            message.channel.bulkDelete(args[1]);
message.delete()
            break;
```